# Can we use Google OAuth in any Android application making network calls to third party?

Tags: android, web-services, authentication, oauth, google-oauth

Which library can be used for OAuth implementation in Android?
Does google OAuth client assembly can be used, even if i don't want to use any google login.

Actually , i am developing an Android Application for some www.abc.com client and they want to use OAuth for authentication. Can you please suggest me some library for this?

Answer (score 0):

You only need to authenticate through Google OAuth if you need to access Google APIs or a user's information. In general, the easiest way to implement Google OAuth in Android is by using the [G+ Sign In Button](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/sign-in).